# Imagemagick on Heroku

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, imagick

Since certain functions of GD is not available on heroku, i have tried imagemagick on heroku for php web apps.

I have changed builpacks to here https://github.com/zapumal/heroku-buildpack-php but it returns php fatal error

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Imagick()
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagick is not a PHP package. Rather, it relies on ImageMagick being installed. You'll need to install it first.

**Edit:**

It looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319961/imagick-on-heroku-is-it-possible) has more details if you've already installed ImageMagick and it's not working. See the first answer.