# Converting SVG XML to PNG on Heroku

Tags: xml, heroku, svg, png, imagemagick-convert

I am working on a web app that allows users to draw an SVG using Raphael.js.

When they post their personal info I use XMLSerializer().serializeToString and submit the output via a hidden form field to be stored into MySQL.

My issue is that I want to later read out this XML data and convert it to a PNG file that can then be mailed back to users later on, and my app is deployed on Heroku.

I'm aware of batik and rmagick but not quite sure how to fit everything together.

I've been going around and around in circles trying to find solutions - would appreciate some direction - thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SVG image to PNG with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319961/imagick-on-heroku-is-it-possible