# How can I fix Heroku imagecreatefromjpeg()

Tags: php, javascript, function, heroku, undefined

heroku report me a error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() ..at line 177, where at line 177 is: 
case 'jpg':
case 'jpeg':
$image_data = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image);
break;

I think heroku does not support jpeg or something, what can I do in that case?

Comment: It does not but you can try  ImageMagick http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321611/1581448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom buildpack with imagick or gd compiled in.

I don't believe the latest version of heroku's official PHP buildpack has support for this, but I've created my own buildpacks for this too.

See https://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php (This version is built on 5.4.11 using PHP-FPM, but you can choose an older tagged branch for 5.3 support using mod_php.)

Comment: thank you for your response. only need to push buildpack to server? sorry I;m not experienced with that.

Comment: I had incorrectly linked to the official heroku buikdpack and not the custom one. How to configure your app to use it is in the README. You may have to make a small edit and git push to heroku after configuring the buuldpack.

Comment: Thank you, I succeeded with that, now I have another problem with: Warning: session_start(): Cannot find serialization handler 'igbinary' which really do not know what that means

Comment: You can add [imagick.so as an extension](https://github.com/alkhoo/heroku-cedar-php-extension)

Comment: @Pustiu314p - Can you upload your solution I have the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

On Heroku, GD is a "shared" extension that you can enable in composer.json. No custom buildpack required, just add the ext-gd line in your `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-gd": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work at first, run `composer update` and try again. Worked for me!

Comment: there is a missing columns after php line

Comment: Working for me.

Comment: @PedroAntônio `composer require ext-gd`

Comment: In that case, you'll have to edit the composer.json file manually and upload it to heroku using whatever method you use to get your source on heroku already.