# TimThumb Call to undefined function imagecreate fromjpeg()

Tags: php, timthumb

I have downloaded [TimThumb](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) renamed the script to index.php and uploaded it to a heroku server.

I get this error when using a jpg image.

```
 [Wed Jul 10 08:01:28 2013] [error]
[client xx] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreate
fromjpeg() in /app/www/index.php on line 1085
```

What is wrong?

The script works fine with .gif and .png images..

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**

I did find a build pack that worked:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/tomaskraina/heroku-buildpack-php-jpeg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether GD library is installed on your server.
Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843862/how-can-i-fix-heroku-imagecreatefromjpeg)

Comment: How do I install the GD libary on heroku?

Comment: I have followed this readme https://github.com/alkhoo/heroku-cedar-php-extension but still get the same error

Comment: Also try to use a custom buildpack with imagemagick https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick

Comment: `git://github.com/ustramooner/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler.git`

Comment: "apt-get install php5-gd" , and "service apache2 reload"