# heroku call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()

Tags: facebook-graph-api, heroku

I have created a simple `facebook app`. That calculate the female friends from your profile and choose any one randomly. and display her image on a predefined template.

to merge `her pic` on the predefined template, I am using function `imagecreatefromjpeg`.

Its working fine on my localhost but when I am trying to run it on server, then I am getting error in error log :

```
call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()
```

The application is located at the url

http://secret-beach-4551.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Check whether GD library is installed on your server. Also check [This Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843862/how-can-i-fix-heroku-imagecreatefromjpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the `GD library` is installed on your server. Also check: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843862/how-can-i-fix-heroku-imagecreatefromjpeg)