# Intervention image on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, intervention

I am working on an app in Laravel which uses Intervention Image library and Imagick to upload and resize images on the fly. Following is my code:

```
public function saveImage($directory, $imageObject) {
        $imageFile = $imageObject->store('app/'.$directory);

        $filename = str_replace('app/'.$directory.'/','',$imageFile);        
        $imageObject = Storage::get($imageFile);

        $img = Image::make($imageObject);
        $img->resize(null, 40, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $imageFile = $img->stream();

        Storage::put('app/'.$directory.'/'.$filename, $imageFile->__toString());

        // $img->save($imagePath);

        return $filename;
    }
```

However the problem occurs on the line `Image::make($imageObject)`. The only error which Heroku returns is 503 Service Unavailable. Please help.

Comment: set your log in config/app to errorlog, i.e. stdout, and you should get more info in your heroku log (logplex), as it states in the docs.

Comment: Thanks mate. It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagick is a library that needs to be installed on the machine. From [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions%7B):

> The following built-in extensions have been built “shared” and can be
>   enabled through composer.json (internal identifier names given in
>   parentheses):

Add the code from this answer to your `composer.json`-https://stackoverflow.com/a/35660753/2460352:

```
...
"require": {
     "ext-imagick": "*",
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you need more robust logging to identify your problem https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging This link has a section about forcing laravel to output errors

Comment: That helped. I updated environment variable in Heroku and found the php errors throwing up right on my screen. The issue was with gd library not installed, although I had set to use Imagick in config/image.php